# How to sort JSON by key

Tags: json

I want to sort by JSON key. However, I want to keep the original representation of the values. For example, if I use jq, the value may change. Is there any recommended tool for this?

For example, when I input the following JSON,

```
{
  "def": 1000000000000000000000,
  "abc": 1.000
}
```

I want to get the following output.

```
{
  "abc": 1.000,
  "def": 1000000000000000000000
}
```

However, if I run `jq -sort-keys`, I will get the following.

```
{
  "abc": 1,
  "def": 1e+21
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find one, so I made one myself.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sort-json-by-object-key